# Use values from sheet 2 to calculate custom function in sheet 1

Tags: google-sheets

I in sheet2 I have a database with column A containing cards, and column B containing their type.

In sheet1 I have a column of cards, and want to return their type in the cell next to each card. When I run the code below, all I get is "Unknown function: 'CC'.", what I am doing wrong?

I am new to coding, so it might be obvious to others than me what I am doing wrong.

```
   function CC(input) {

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getSheetByName('sheet2');

  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues(); // read all data in the sheet

  for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){ // iterate row by row and examine data in column A
    if(data[n][0].toString().match(input)){ 
      var ct = data[n][1] 
      return ct
      };//
  }

  Logger.log(data)

}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Lookup](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570?hl=en) function?

For example, in C2, put the formula:

```
=lookup(B2,'sheet2'!A:A,'sheet2'!D:D)
```

Which means: check column A of sheet2 for anything that matches B2, then return the corresponding value in column D